# Install Bootstrap4 manually

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to include the Bootstrap4 files manually in my project and I am wondering what are all the files for and which ones I really need finally.
Using CDN I just need two to embed two files (bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js). E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After downloading Bootstrap4 I have the following files available:

[image]

I would appreciate a little hint. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I found the answer...https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/

Comment: Did you [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents/)? It seems clear that you only *need* the `min.js` and `min.css` as included when you run off CDN

Comment: Yes, sorry again. I posted this question a little early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.bundle.min.js are the files you need. The JavaScript bundle includes Popper but you’ll need to manually add jQuery as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be like me, read the documentation properly at:

getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/contents